# custom sorting order for a vector

Tags: java

I want to sort a vector based on user defined order.

here is my code snippet

```
class xxx {
      private String xxName;
      private String xxMapName
//getters and setter
}


// main 
public class Test {
public static void main(String s) {

List<xxx> options = new Vector<xxx>();
```

scenarion1: (IF vector contains ISE_BASE,ISE_ADVANCED,ISE)

```
xxx x1 = new xxx();
x1.setXxName("s1");
x1.setXxMapName("ISE_BASE");
options.add(x1);


xxx x2 = new xxx();
x2.setXxName("s1");
x2.setXxMapName("ISE_ADVANCED");
options.add(x2);

xxx x2 = new xxx();
x2.setXxName("s1");
x2.setXxMapName("ISE");
options.add(x2);
```

scenarion2:(IF vector contains any two of ISE_BASE,ISE_ADVANCED,ISE)

```
xxx x1 = new xxx();
x1.setXxName("s1");
x1.setXxMapName("ISE_BASE");
options.add(x1);


xxx x2 = new xxx();
x2.setXxName("s1");
x2.setXxMapName("ISE_ADVANCED");
options.add(x2);

}
}
```

I want to sort vector based on xxMapName(property of  xxx). Here the order should be always `ISE_BASE,ISE,ISE_ADVANCED`.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement comparator interface and use

```
Collections.sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c)
```

Comment: hi rafael, thanks for your suggestion. I want exact comparison logic for mentioned scenarios

Answer (score 0):

Override compareTo()

```
class xxx implements Comparable<xxx> {
      private String xxName;
      private String xxMapName
//getters and setter

    public int compareTo(xxx obj) {
        if (this.xxMapName.equals("ISE_BASE")) {
            return -1;
        } else if (obj.xxMapName.equals("ISE_BASE")) {
            return 1;       
        } else if (this.xxMapName.equals("ISE")) {
            return -1;
        } else if (obj.xxMapName.equals("ISE")) {
            return 1;
        } else if (this.xxMapName.equals("ISE_ADVANCED")) {
            return -1;
        } else if (obj.xxMapName.equals("ISE_ADVANCED")) {
            return 1;
        }   
        return 0;
    }
}
```

after which you can use `Collections.sort(options)`

Comment: @SatishCh i have updated answer. Please check. This sorts in order ISE_BASE,ISE,ISE_ADVANCED.